# Fedora 31 - grubby --args="systems.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=0" broke the system

Tags: fedora, gnome, docker, cgroups

I upgraded to Fedora 31 today. All good. I came across issue with Docker so I found the solution to run

`grubby --args="systems.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=0"`

and then `grub2-mkconfig`

Now, systems won't start into Gnome... stuck at GDM Started and that's it. I can get into tty2, but no way to run GDM. [image]

Answer (score 0):

You can boot from live-CDROM, mount your local disk manually and then undo the changes you made in `grub.cfg`.

Comment: I edited to make it more of an answer, but it would really be helpful if you could explain how to do this. Your solution involves many steps (mounting the local drive, finding the `/boot` partition if it is separate, the OP isn't even aware of `grub.cfg` since they used another tool). Since you don't explain how to do any of these things, I fear your answer won't be very useful to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that there were some other uncommitted changes in your `/etc/default/grub' that were committed when you did the grub2-mkconfig.  Are you sure about those nvidia driver options?  Were they fully applied earlier?  Sounds like your GPU drivers or modeset are invalid. Try to remove nouveau from blacklist and modeset?